# Hibernate: Updating existing Entities with 1:n relationship and backref

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

first of all: My understanding of hibernate is not very deep. Most of my code is trial and error. I'm using Hibernate 4.2.6 with annotations and the hibernate.cfg.xml and it's a Postgres database underneath.
I wasn't able to find a solution on this one:

I have an abstract super class:

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Then there is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.utils.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Barn extends AbstractEntity {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "barn", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Horse> horses = new ArrayList<>();
    //other stuff and getters and setters

    public void addHorseToBarn(Horse horse) {
        horse.setBarn(this);
        this.horses.add(horse);
    }
}
```

And finally the class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.utils.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Horse extends AbstractEntity { 
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "barn_id")
    private Barn barn;
    // other stuff and getters and setters
}
```

Hibernate creates a Table for horse (with a foreign key to barn), barn and then barn_horse with the ids in it.
I already have created a Barn and persisted it and also there is a persited Horse.
Now I want to create the realtionship between two of them with the following code:

```
public void takeHorseIntoBarn(Barn barn, Horse horse) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Barn b = (Barn) session.load(Barn.class, barn.getId());
        Horse h = (Horse) session.load(Horse.class, horse.getId());
        b.addHorseToBarn(h);
        session.update(h);
        session.update(b);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

In the console I only see an output for updating the Horse. When I take a look into my database afterwards, there is no entry in barn_horse. And in the Table horse the key of the Barn isn't there.
I've tried serveral methods and I wouldn't ask here, if I didn't read and try out many things. So please, have you any ideas what the problem is? Thanks!

Update: 
What I found out so far: If I remove mappedBy and add a Cascade.ALL to Barn I'll get the wanted entry in barn_horses table but in the entity Horse I won't get the id of the barn inserted. From Barn I am able to get it's horses. But since I'm using a Barn in Horse as a backref, I guess I need 'mappedBy', because I want the Barn to be accessable via Horse and without mappedBy the id of the barn is not inserted into Horse. So this is not the solution I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it! This is how I did it:

In Barn class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "barn", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Horse> horses = new ArrayList<>();

public void addHorse(Horse horse) {
    this.horses.add(horse);
    horse.setBarn(this);
}
```

In Horse class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "barn_id")
private Barn barn;
```

To update the relation:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Barn b = (Barn) session.load(Barn.class, barn.getId());
    Horse h = (Horse) session.load(Horse.class, horse.getId());
    b.addHorse(h);
    session.update(b);
    session.update(h);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch(Exception e) {
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, u missing referenceColumn in ManyToOne part?
And I think [cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade) is what u want.

Comment: referenceColumn in ManyToOne? I don't understand what you want me to do. And as far as I understood Cascade, I thought by using an update on both entities, I wouldn't need d cascade. In my tries I was using cascade.all which didn't help.